# Fortran Arrays change values automatically

Tags: arrays, fortran, intel-fortran

I am doing my maser thesis on WIND turbine simulation On ANSYS CFX.To calculate a parameter I have to use a code written in FORTRAN. I am facing a very weird type of problem and need your help.The complete fortran code is quite long but I will only post the subroutine in the code that is causing problem.

I am using a subroutine to divide the blade in a no of radial elements.Two types of division is used and the radial positions of the elements are then stored in two 1-D arrays RI and RJ.

Later in the code, I got some error and I traced it back to this subroutine that it is not giving me correct values of RJ .The subroutine is giving correct values of RI. Then I displayed the results of RJ using the same loop in which it is calculated [correct values of RJ](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8j0LN.png). Fortunately the values of RJ were correct. Then in the same subroutine, immediately after that loop, I started another loop to display the values of RJ again and unfortunately this time they were not correct [incorrect values of RJ](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xReWr.png) even there is nothing between the two loops that could change the values of RJ. seemingly every element of RJ is replaced with the next element of RI.  Hence I came to know that here is the error originating. I have rechecked the program and seemingly there is no error and the error is originating somewhere inside the subroutine. I am using another program on fortran without ANSYS CFX to calculate wind turbine performance using same subroutine and this problem is NOT coming in that program although the two subroutines  in  the two programs are exactly same. I need help in this matter as I am stuck in it for past few days. I am using Intel fortran compiler that comes with INTEL COMPOSER.

The subroutinea are as follows

```
CALL INIT(M,PI,PREC,R,HUBRAD,RI,RJ)

SUBROUTINE INIT(M,PI,PREC,R,HUBRAD,RI,RJ)


  INTEGER:: M
  REAL:: PI,PREC,R,HUBRAD
  REAL:: RI(41),RJ(41)
  !,RRI,RRJ)

    CALL LLPOINTS (PI,PREC,R,HUBRAD,M,RI,RJ)


    return
    End Subroutine

    SUBROUTINE LLPOINTS (PI,PREC,R,HUBRAD,M,RI,RJ)

  !Input arguments: M,Pi, PREC, R, HUBRAD 
  !Output arguments : RI, RJ

  INTEGER:: M
  REAL::PREC,R,HUBRAD
  REAL:: RI(41),RJ(41)
  INTEGER :: J
  character*100 ::string1, string2, string3

  CALL MESAGE( 'WRITE', 'subroutine INIT START' )  

  CALL MESAGE( 'WRITE', "RI   RJ    DJ")

  DO J=1,M+1   


        IF (J.LT.M+1) THEN   
        RI(J)=0.5E+00*(1.E+00+HUBRAD/R)-0.5E+00*(1.E+00-HUBRAD/R)
       &*COS((J-0.5E+00)*PI/M)

        RJ(J)=0.5E+00*(1.E+00+HUBRAD/R)-0.5E+00*(1.E+00-HUBRAD/R)
       &*COS((J-1.E+00)*PI/M)


        IF (ABS(RI(J)).LT.(1/PREC)) THEN

              STOP 
        ENDIF

        ELSE
           RJ(J)=1.E+00

          END IF


          write (string1,*) RI(J)
          write (string2,*) RJ(J)


          CALL MESAGE( 'WRITE', string1//' '//string2) 

      END DO

      CALL MESAGE( 'WRITE','ri     rj')
      do j =1,m

          write (string1,*) RI(J)
          write (string2,*) RJ(J)
          CALL MESAGE( 'WRITE', string1//' '//string2 ) 

      end do
      CALL MESAGE( 'WRITE', 'subroutine LLINE OK' )  

  END SUBROUTINE
```

You would be wondering why LLPOINTS is INSIDE INIT subroutine without any reason. Actually in the original program the subroutine INIT has a lot of other subroutines. I used only LLPOINTS and discarded rest of them as I did not need them

I have checked that my program does not have implicit none in any of the subroutines which according to my limited knowledge should be present. When I added implicit none to all subroutines, a number of compilation errors have occurred and seemingly in those errors, I have found that there were problems related to the declarations of a number of variables . I have resolved these issues and now when all issues are resolved, I have got the following error in compilation which was not coming before implicit none.

Error:unresolved external symbol LLINE referenced in function ACD_Dp.

I dont know how to deal with this error

Comment: You might want to try https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/intel-visual-fortran-compiler-for-windows

Comment: Could you show how this subroutine (`LLPOINTS`) is called, and how the actual arguments for `RI` and `RJ` are defined? The actual arguments may be incorrectly passed such that they point to memory regions with only a difference of by 1.

Comment: basically the argument  "m" is the number into which the blade of the turbine is divided.The value of m is read from another input file and is passed on to this subroutine. I have already tested, the value of m is passed correctly to this subroutine. The size of RI and RJ are deliberately limited to 41. This is done to avoid allocatable arrays. By default this program can only work till m=40 elements ( the division into two arrays RI n RJ is such that the number of RI elements are equal to m and the number of RJ elements are equal to m+1) . Any value of m less than 40 should work.

Comment: check my edited question for calling of (LLifine)  subroutine

Comment: Could you also show how `RI` and `RJ` are defined in the subroutine that has the statement `CALL INIT(M,PI,PREC,R,HUBRAD,RI,RJ)`? (My another guess is that `RI` and `RJ` are declared as scalars there.) Also, could you try attaching the `-check all` (for Linux/Mac) or `/check:all` (for Windows) option to compile? (sorry if the option for Windows is not correct)

Comment: Use relevant tags to get more attention.

Comment: check my edited question at the end

Comment: Do you have any function (or subroutine) named `LLINE` somewhere? And how is `LLINE` used in your routine? The compiler thinks that `LLINE` is a function, while it cannot find its definition in any source code (at link time).

Answer (score 1):

The weird behavior might originate from some (incorrect) actual arguments rather than subroutines themselves. To explain this, we first consider a simplified version of `INIT()` and `LLPOINTS()` as follows:

```
subroutine INIT ( a, b )
    implicit none
    real :: a( 5 ), b( 5 )

    call LLPOINTS ( a, b )
end subroutine

subroutine LLPOINTS ( a, b )
    implicit none
    real :: a( 5 ), b( 5 )
    integer :: i

    print *, "output (1):"
    do i = 1, 5
        a( i ) = i                !! set some values to a(:) and b(:)
        b( i ) = i * 100
        print *, a( i ), b( i )   !! check the values
    enddo

    print *, "output (2):"
    do i = 1, 4
        print *, a( i ), b( i )   !! check the values again
    enddo
end subroutine
```

This program sets some values to `a(:)` and `b(:)` and prints their values twice for double check (as in the OP's program). Now we consider the main program:

```
program main
    real :: a( 5 ), b( 5 )
    call INIT ( a, b )
end
```

which gives the expected result (with `ifort test.f90` with v14.0):

```
 output (1):
   1.000000       100.0000
   2.000000       200.0000
   3.000000       300.0000
   4.000000       400.0000
   5.000000       500.0000
 output (2):
   1.000000       100.0000
   2.000000       200.0000
   3.000000       300.0000
   4.000000       400.0000
```

Next, let us suppose that `a` and `b` are declared erroneously as scalar variables

```
program main
    real :: a, b
    call INIT ( a, b )
end
```

or even with no declaration (i.e., with default `implicit real(a-h,o-z)` rule)

```
program main
    call INIT ( a, b )
end
```

We then obtain

```
 output (1):
   1.000000       100.0000
   2.000000       200.0000
   3.000000       300.0000
   4.000000       400.0000
   5.000000       500.0000
 output (2):
   1.000000       2.000000
   2.000000       3.000000
   3.000000       4.000000
   4.000000       5.000000
```

whose pattern seems to be very similar to that of the OP's output (i.e., all the elements are shifted by 1 in output (2)). That is, the reason for this weird behavior might be that we are passing scalars and accessing an invalid memory region (assuming that `a` and `b` are aligned contiguously in memory, with some trailing memory area). If so, memory mapping between `main()` and `LLPOINTS()` may look like this:

```
a       b      NG     NG     NG     NG
---------------------------------------
a(1)    a(2)   a(3)   a(4)   a(5)
        b(1)   b(2)   b(3)   b(4)   b(5)
```

If this is the case, since `a(i+1) = b(i)`, we obtain the weird result in output (2) above. We can confirm this by inserting lines like

```
if ( loc( a(2) ) == loc( b(1) ) ) stop "trapped (ifort)"
```

in `LLPOINTS()`. And more importantly, if we attach

```
ifort -check test.f90
```

option, we can detect this automatically (with segmentation fault). So could you try this option to see whether this is the case...?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you are right. I have put the following lines

```
If ( loc( RJ(1) ) == loc( RI(2) ) ) then
call mesage ('write','trapped (ifort)')

stop

End If
```

and I have got the error , printing trapped (ifort). 
But the thing is , I have not declared scalar arguments RI, RJ anywhere. I have always declared them as vectors RI(41) and RJ(41)

Comment: Nice, I guess we are probably on the right track (i.e., some problem of actual arguments). There are several other possibilities for causing this error, but I believe attaching `implicit none` to relevant routines as well as attaching `-check all` (or `/check:all`) might be more useful (than guessing) to give some warning or error messages (hopefully!). Including relevant routines into a module is also useful for checking subroutine interfaces (e.g., whether the numbers and types of arguments are correct). I have added one more approach in my answer also.

Comment: so what do you suggest ? How should I proceed ? I am not a professional programmer and have little background in programming except knowing basic hings to work. A bit more explanation on how to solve the problem will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Hmm, did you try `ifort -check all` (or `ifort /check:all`) ? From this point on, we cannot go further until you get more information from warning or error message(s) with this kind of compiler opitons, or include more relevant codes into the question. Is it tricky to add this option in your compiler environment? (I've never used Windows for Intel fortran, so sorry in that case.)

Comment: One more try: Could you include the main program (with `program` statement), the routine including `CALL INIT(...)` statement, and all subroutines that connect these two program units into the Question (by editing it)? My guess is that there would be some problem in argument passing in these subroutines (the most likely case is that there's no declaration at some routine, resulting in scalars due to the implicit rule). Also, please try to include your "answer" as "Update" in your question (to gather all the info in one place).

Comment: Because this might also be some issue related to Intel + Windows , I think it would also be useful to ask the Intel forum also (see the first comment in your Question).